# R markdown not knitting because of parse raw had been removed

Tags: r, markdown

I've been having problems on knitting Rmarkdown, and it's been frustrating that I have no idea what to do. Every time I knit them, it always ended up with an error like this

```
output file: -R--Pengenalan_R.knit.md

--parse-raw/-R has been removed. Use +raw_html or +raw_tex extension.

Unknown option ---Pengenalan_R.knit.md.
Try pandoc.exe --help for more information.
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 6
Execution halted
```

I've also tried to reinstall my Rstudio but it doesn't work either. Does anyone have a clue how to solve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post all your Rmd script

Comment: Looks like the output filename (and therefore the input Rmd filename) might be a problem? Does it start with `-R--` as indicated?